# NServiceBus saga spread on several servers

Tags: nservicebus, saga

I have a complex business logic process that includes 4 different servers (each performs different part of the process).
I used WCF web service to every server.

Now I want to use NServiceBus in this process. The saga feature sounds exactly what I need how ever I don't quit understand how to implement this process - do I need to create handlers in the saga so that each of them will call a webService?

Or can I put the same saga host on every server so that each server will handle it's part of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the orchestration between the servers performed as an NServiceBus saga, where it sends messages (rather than calling webservices) to the other servers. You'd have message handlers on those servers which perform the logic, and return messages back (as needed).

All that being said, a more detailed explanation of your process and the logic itself may lead to an alternative design.